# What is regex to match full path to file that has alphanumeric name ending with digits only?

Tags: regex

I have a collection of strings. They are full absolute paths to files. From this list, I want to select those paths that contain filename that ends with underscore followed by three digits, followed by extension name.

The filename shall have to start with a letter and not a digit or underscore, it can then contain any number of letters and numbers and underscores. At end it must have underscore followed by three digits before the extension.

I tried to use \w, but this already contains digits so will match with even those files that do not end with digits. I only got to these two but they are not good enough:

```
\w(_[0-9]{3})\.(vhd|vhdl|sv|v)$ 
(_[0-9]{3})\.(vhd|vhdl|sv|v)$
```

Here are a few examples:

These will fail match:

```
./Qsys_Systems/MY_SYS_TB/simulation/submodules/1_MY_SYS_TB_mm_interconnect_0_router.sv
./Qsys_Systems/MY_SYS_TB/simulation/submodules/_MY_SYS_TB_mm_interconnect_0_router.sv
./Qsys_Systems/MY_SYS_TB/simulation/submodules/MY_SYS_TB_mm_interconnect_0_router.sv
```

These will pass match:

```
./Qsys_Systems/MY_SYS_TB/simulation/submodules/MY_SYS_TB_mm_interconnect_0_router_001.sv
./Qsys_Systems/MY_SYS_TB/simulation/submodules/MY_SYS_TB_mm_interconnect_0_router_002.sv
./Qsys_Systems/MY_SYS_TB/simulation/submodules/MY_SYS_TB_mm_interconnect_0_router_004.sv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you can use

```php
^(?:.*/)?[a-zA-Z]\w*_\d{3}\.(?:vhd|vhdl|sv|v)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLyDFA/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `(?:.*/)?` - an optional sequence of any text (any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible) and then a `/` char
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
- `\w*` - zero or more letters/digits/`_`
- `_` - underscore
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\.` - a `.`
- `(?:vhd|vhdl|sv|v)` - one of the extensions
- `$` - end of string.

If your regex flavor is POSIX ERE, use capturing groups and `[0-9]` to match digits: `^(.*/)?[[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*_[0-9]{3}\.(vhd|vhdl|sv|v)$`.

Provided the regex flavor supports Unicode property classes, you may replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{L}` that matches any Unicode letter, or with a `[[:alpha:]]` POSIX character class.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLyDFA/1).

Comment: The thing is that, using the ^ makes the pattern fail. I shall put some examples in question.

Comment: Please  make correction to the long regex just after the bullet points. This appears to be the solution ^(?:.*)?[a-zA-Z]\w*_\d{3}\.(?:vhd|vhdl|sv|v)$
Could you kindly explain what the (?:.*) does?